# find bigger and minimum number in an array using pointer and linear search?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have two questions about pointer. I tried to solve them by myself but I couldn't. First is

> Find the bigger and smaller number in an array using pointers.

This my attempt for the first one:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[]={8,9,5,23,12};
    int min;
    int i;
    int *arr_pt;
    int big;
    min = arr[];    
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]<min)
            min = arr[i];
    }
}
```

The second one is

> Find a given number in an integer array using linear search algorithm with pointers.

I don't know where should I put the pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i;
    int y;
    int arr[];
    int found;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(arr[]==y)
            found=1;
        if(found==1)
            printf("%d is found",y);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever close a scope with `}`? Indentation is similarly sad.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but this seems like a task you were handed in a programming class. Maybe it is better to ask your teacher for explanation? You will earn much more that way than by waiting for someone to present the correct answer on a silver platter. Maybe read a bit on pointers ? You can use Google or any other search engine to find information. For example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_array_of_pointers.htm

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes that was a task. I tried to solve it by myself then i asked my teacher about it and he gave this code. He said this will help you.

Comment: @LogicalStuff First i'm new on this site. Second i'm new in programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>

auto minmax = std::minmax_element(std::begin(values), std::end(values));

std::cout << "min element " << *(minmax.first) << "\n";
std::cout << "max element " << *(minmax.second) << "\n";
```

**Complexity:**

At most max(floor(3/2(N−1)), 0) applications of the predicate, where N = std::distance(first, last).

C++ is beautiful ;)

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know they added that to C++11.  Going to add that into my list of tricks.

Comment: Thank you for your help brother.

Comment: @Moayad dont forget to mark it as solved ;) No problems!